# How to download PDF files under each row in Excel sheet using Python Script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have an Excel workbook which has list of URL's each row has a specific URL to a PDF, I am working to download each PDF from every URL and store it in a separate folder. I tried doing that , but ended up downloading a single PDF file every time. I am only downloading files whose status code is '200'. Below is my code :-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import wget
import requests
count = 0
df = pd.read_excel('Sample Training Data.xlsx')
row_count = print(len(df))
for col in df.columns:
    for url in df[col]:
        ##check if the url has .pdf extension
        if '.pdf' in url:
            filename = url
            r = requests.get(filename)
            ##check the status code
            if r.status_code == 200:
                print(filename)
                count = count + 1
                for i in range(0, count):
                with open(r"D:\Juwi\Downloaded PDF\file_" + str(i) + ".pdf", 'wb') as f:
                       f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of the last `for`? Are you writing the `r.content` to all files starting from `i=0` to `i=count`?

Comment: The indentation is fixed for this in runtime, and I am trying to download each of the pdf in a respective folder with name separated with variable 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

instead of

```
for col in df.columns:
```

Comment: It Gives attribute error - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'row'

Comment: @SourabhRaj Sorry I had the wrong code. See the change to `for index, row in df.iterrows():`

Comment: It Still gives the below error :-
KeyError: "None of [Index...... dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the urls are in column `0` of the dataframe you can extract the column to a Python `list`.

```
url_list = df.iloc[:,0].tolist()    # Change 0 to another number if urls in a different column
```

Then you can loop through `url_list`.